# Android mediaplayer getDuration() returns 0 for some mp3 files

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager

I have a large collection of mp3 files on my server and i'm using android media player for playing them. The problem is for almost all of them getDuration() method returns 0. I uploaded sample mp3 file and put it somewhere on my server. mediaplayer works perfectly fine with that file!!

I can't understand what's the different. My knowledge about audio files is very limited. Can anyone give me a suggestion what to do?

can I somehow modify mp3 files on my server so mediaplayer can read the metadata?

BTW this problem occurs only on Android. My links on google chrome are fine. and google shows the duration of file right from the beginning of playing when only small percentage of file is downloaded.

Comment: Sample code where this is called?

Answer (score 0):

We finally fixed this issue by replacing our web server. We replaced tomcat with apache and it fixed the issue. I don't exactly know why